# Можно ли вызвать функцию контроллера из другой функции

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть функция при выполнении которой должна вызваться функция `UpdateDetails` контроллера `MainController`

```
function MainController($ngRedux, $scope, $http, $timeout) {
    var app = this;

    app.mapStateToThis = function(state) {
        return state;
    };

    function UpdateDetails(item) {
        console.log('stockNo' + item.stockno);    
    }

}
```

Возможно ли это сделать?

Comment: нет, за пределами `MainController` функция `UpdateDetails` недоступна

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно. Вот пример:

В самом верху проекта:

```
var SharedObject = null;
```

Ваш код далее:

```
function MainController($ngRedux, $scope, $http, $timeout) {
    var app = this;

    SharedObject = this;

    app.mapStateToThis = function(state) {
        return state;
    };

    SharedObject.UpdateDetails = function(item) {
        console.log('stockNo' + item.stockno);    
    }

}
```

И теперь где-то далеко можно:

```
if(SharedObject)
    SharedObject.UpdateDetails(...);
```

Как я считаю - программирование это такая вещь, где можно **все**, правильно спрашивать "как" =)

Comment: очевидно, твой вариант не сработает, потому что в твоем `this`, который ты сохраняешь в _глобальную_ переменную не сохранена нужная функция. Не говоря уже про то, что сам такой подход не очень

Comment: Да, спасибо, то что нужно! (внёс правки, указанные @Grundy для корректной работы)

Comment: @a.tarasevich, плохое решение, если тебе надо использовать что-то в нескольких местах перенеси это в сервис, а не делай костыли с глобальным объектом